# Как перемешать список, сохранив индексы?

Tags: python, массивы, случайные-числа, shuffle

Есть массив и его сохранённая копия. Над массивом делаются некоторые преобразования, затем он перемешивается, например с помощью `numpy.random.shuffle(x)`.
Вопрос: есть ли простой (без лишних сущностей) способ сохранить соответствие индексов, чтоб можно было установить, каким значениям сохранённой копии исходного массива соответствуют значения преобразованного-перемешанного массива?

Answer (score 2):

Псевдокод:

```
Массив
Соответствие = МассивИзЧиселДиапазона( 0, Массив.длина - 1 ).Перемешать()
ПеремешанныйМассив = []

Для Ключ=>Значение из Соответствие:
  ПеремешанныйМассив.Добавить( Массив[ Значение ] )

Вернуть ( Соответствие, ПеремешанныйМассив )
```

Как вариант - создать класс обёртку с методами:

```
get( ИндексПеремешанного )
getSrc( ИндексИсходного )
```

Внутри - 2 массива: исходный и перемешанного соответствия

Answer (score 2):

Каждый из элементов сделать кортежем вида (индекс, значение). Перемешать. Как индекс воспринимать первый элемент кортежа.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
l = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]
x = list(enumerate(l))
random.shuffle(x)
indices, l = zip(*x)
print(l) # Перемешанный список
print(indices) # Исходные индексы
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39832773/getting-previous-index-values-of-a-python-list-items-after-shuffling)

Answer (score 0):

Ну, если мы реанимируем старые темы, то можно предложить решение через словарь:

```
import random
a = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42,49,50]
b=dict(zip(a,range(len(a)))) #Или любой другой способ перехода от списка к словарю  
lt=list(b.items())
random.shuffle(list(b.items()))

print (lt)
```

Его преимущество в том, что вы получаете не два разных массива, связанных по индексу, а просто список пар "Значение - Индекс_в_исходном_Массиве", что проще, при дальнейшей работе с этими данными. Даже распечатать результат -  и то проще. В данном случае:

```
[(23, 4), (4, 0), (49, 6), (16, 3), (42, 5), (15, 2), (50, 7), (8, 1)]
```